# How to ask if power is there?

Tags: sentence-construction, american-english

Well, sometimes we are having power cuts in our area. But before looking for other houses we cannot be sure if it's due to a general problem with electrical power, or if it's a problem on our side. So we have to ask our neighbours for this. Can anyone please tell me how to do that?

Comment: Hey, Joe, our electricity's off. Have you guys got power?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like "Hey [name], is your house's power out?"

Comment: Don't use *house's*; it's simply, "Is your power out?"

Comment: Or, "Is the power out at your house?"