# Is "there has been outage in my house for the past 8 hours" correct?

Tags: prepositions, passive-voice, indefinite-article

> There has been outage in my house for the past 8 hours.

I want to know if there's a better way of saying it or if this is grammatically correct.

Comment: It is correct.You could also say: We have had a (power) outage in my house for the past 8 hours. We have had a power cut in my house for the past 8 hours.

Comment: I would prefer to say "at my house" instead, where its the power company's fault, not the wiring inside your house.

Comment: Related: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/16266/a-verb-to-describe-a-power-cut.

Comment: No, it's not quite right.  Personally, I'd say "The power's been out at my house for the last eight hours."

Comment: I've been reading news articles to improve my English, and I've noticed that they generally use "in" with house and "at" with "home".

Comment: @Vaibhav - That's a good observation. However, a power outage would be one exception; we would use "at my house" when referring to a general location or address. For example: _Can you please deliver the new machine between 10 and 2? I should be **at** my house then_.

Answer (score 4):

"Outage" is something the service provider would normally use:

> We are working on an outage in your neighborhood.

The customer would normally use "out" or "down" depending on the service:

> My power's been out for 8 hours.
>
> My internet's been down for 8 hours.

Answer (score 2):

If we change "outage in" to "a power outage at", the sentence becomes grammatically correct.

> There has been A POWER outage AT my house for the past 8 hours.

That still sounds a bit odd though. Usually a power outage refers to everybody that lost power, not just your house. I think this sounds better:

> There has been A POWER outage IN MY NEIGHBORHOOD for the past 8 hours.

I also like boatseller's answer. He gives the more colloquial way to describe a power outage, using the phrase "the power's out".

Comment: Nice answer! I like the contrasting "neighborhood* example. +1 and please keep the answers coming! :)